# Address book: after updating a phone number, the old one keeps registered

Tags: contacts

The following happens on a Google Pixel 3a with Android 12.

One of my contacts having changed its phone number, I updated it in my address book.

After tapping `Save` the previous number keeps displayed in addition to (and before) the new one.
More: if I tap the contact for calling, it's the old number that is called!

Nevertheless, going back inside of the card, I see only the new number; but one more time registering shows anew the two numbers.
Strangely, at the opposite, if I look at the address book through Google-contacts on my (synchronized) PC it only shows the new number.

Comment: As a French user I assume your phone also uses that language and the `Register` button you mention is a (non-matching) translation from French to English as in Android Contacts app there is no Register button. Have you checked if your contacts are synced correctly into Google cloud - assuming you have a Google account on your phone and clloud sync active (see https://contacts.google.com)

Comment: Just for clarity, are you using the built-in (Google) Contacts and (Google) Phone app?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes I'm using the built-in Google apps.

Comment: @Robert 1 - You're right: I'm a French user, and to finalize update operation I must tap the button  {Enregistrer}. 2 - Yes I have a Google account on my phone, and I suppose I can trust the sync, since my change was reflected immediately and correctly on contacts.google.com while it remains erroneous on the phone.

Comment: In the English UI the button is always named `Save` (when creating or editing a contact). I have updated your question to avoid confusion. Regarding your question: Contacts can have multiple phone numbers. May be the contact you have edited had two times the same number and you have only changed one of it? Or the contact is a combined contact - Contacts allows you to "combine" contacts (show two contacts of the same person as one).

Comment: @Robert Thanks for editing my question. Also thanks for the suggestions, but I must insist: when in update mode on the phone, only one phone number appears (I had overwritten the old one in place), and this is correctly reflected by the PC version of the contact card.